# AWS RDS odbc driver MS SQL Server in R returning "nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [RStudio][SqlServer] Failed to locate Server/Instance Specified."

Tags: r, sql-server, amazon-web-services, shiny, rodbc

```
con <- DBI::dbConnect(odbc::odbc(),

Driver   = "SQLServer",
Server   = "xxx.xxx.rds.amazonaws.com,1433",
Database = "pws",
UID      = "johndoe",
PWD      = "password",
Port     = "1433")
```

Output:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1021: 00000: [RStudio][SqlServer] Failed to locate Server/Instance Specified.

My AWS RDS SQL Server database is open to remote connections and I have successfully connected to it in SSMS and Excel remotely using the endpoint provided.

Any feedback would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe you should not add the port to the Server name. Remove that and give it a try.

Comment: Same error when removing the port from the server name

Comment: I never seen a driver name like that with no spaces. Consider using the recommended *ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server*. Check installed with PowerShell's `Get-OdbcDriver` or R's `odbc::odbcListDrivers`.

Comment: I had a similar issue with odbc (not AWS related but SQL) and found that installing odbc 1.2.2 resolved the issue. Worth trying.

Comment: @PaulvanOppen that didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Try adding `Trusted_Connection = "False"` or `Trusted_Connection = "No"` to the `dbConnect` parameters. I've seen it default to `Yes` despite having `Uid` and `Pwd` specified.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Thanks but no luck with that approach.